# Shared object between loader & action does not update after action is called in Remix.run?

Tags: remix.run

I have a mock database for playing around with some loaders and actions.

Here's the rough layout:

```js
const db = { key: "bar" }

export const action = async ({ request }) => {
     db.key = "foo"
}

export const loader = async ({ request }) => {
    return json(db)
}
```

I have an issue though. When the action is called, it successfully updates `db.key`, however, the loader is called afterwards & the value is `{key: "bar" }`. Does anyone know why the object is not updated when the loader is called again?

Answer (score 0):

I think that there is something related to ["Data Writes"](https://remix.run/docs/en/v1/guides/data-writes) topic.
Whenever a form is submitted it reload all of the data for all of the routes on the page. Thats why many people reach for global state management libraries like redux.

I don't know if it helps but here I got a simple way where you can send a post request, update it with the action and load the content searching at the URL with the loader.

```js
export const action: ActionFunction = async ({ request }) => {
  const form = await request.formData();
  const key = form.get("key");
  return redirect(`/?key=${key}_updated`);
};

export const loader: LoaderFunction = async ({ request }: any) => {
  const url = new URL(request.url);
  const key = url.searchParams.get("key");
  return json({ key });
};

export default function Index() {
  const loaderData = useLoaderData();
    
  return (
    <div>
      <span>loaderData: {loaderData.key}</span>
      <Form method="post">
        <input type="text" id="key" name="key" defaultValue={loaderData.key} />
        <button>Submit</button>
      </Form>
    </div>
  );
}
```